# Hovering over name to change color in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make the text for a user hover and change color when the mouse is moved over it, but I can't seem to get it working. I know how to do it in CSS, but I'm trying to learn how to do the same thing with JavaScript. Any help would be appreciated

```
const data = [
  { fname: 'esme', lname: 'sanchez', id: 1892038, isTherapist: true },
];

for (const user of data) {
  console.log(
    `${user.lname[0].toUpperCase() + user.lname.slice(1)}, ${
      user.fname[0].toUpperCase() + user.fname.slice(1)
    }`
  );
}

document.getElementById('data').addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
  document.getElementsById('data').style.backgroundColor = crimson;
});

document.getElementById('data').addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
  document.getElementsById('data').style.backgroundColor = yellow;
});
```

Comment: you are just missing `'`, e.g. `document.getElementsById('data').style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';`

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia thank you, I missed that. But it is still giving me a Reference Error of "document is undefined" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mispelled `document.getElementById` inside the callbacks. Try replacing this

```js
document.getElementsById('data').style.backgroundColor = crimson;
```

by this

```js
document.getElementById('data').style.backgroundColor = 'crimson';
```

Also, I don't know if you declared a variable called `crimson` or if you are doing it because its similar to the css `crimson` color alias. If you are replace it, javascript doesn't have global color aliases out of the box.

And don't forget to read the error messages on the browser console (F12 or Ctrl + Shift + I) to have more info on why things break

Comment: thank you, underestimated how many typos I made. It's corrected but it's still kicking back the same Reference error. I'm going through other Stack Overflow questions regarding this error but none of them seems to work so far.

Comment: Can you paste the stacktrace?

Comment: ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\JS101.io\challenge.js:21:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47

Comment: It looks like your code is running in environment without the `document` object (like node or deno). Is that code supposed to run there?

Comment: It is. have node installed.

Comment: You have to make sure that code runs on the browser, since `window` and `document` don't exist in node

Comment: it does work in the browser, in the console it shows the same error, but the page loads with the user data just fine so I'm not really sure what the issue is.

Comment: none. This is all in vanilla JS. The challenge is to solve it using only JavaScript.

Comment: Then you should look at how the code is organized, since it looks like the code for the browser is running on the server

Comment: Ok, I'll do that. The first time I'm encountering this but glad I am, will force me to find the solution for the future.